# referencing a f# fsharp libary in blazor

Tags: f#, reference, blazor

I am trying to reference a F# project(Class Library) in Blazor.
I add this to the Blazor.csproj and it compiles.

```
<ItemGroup>
<ProjectReference Include="FSharpLibrary\FSharpLibrary.fsproj" />
```

Great.
But when I add it to _Imports.razor I get the error message  :

The type or namespace name 'FSharpLibrary' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Am I missing something or is this just not possible in Blazor?

Comment: What exactly did you put in your `_Imports.razor` file? This worked for me with no problem: `@using FSharpLibrary`.

Comment: Hello Brian, the same as you did. @using FSharpLibrary

Comment: I referenced it in VS Code. Could that be a problem?

Comment: I think there's probably some problem with your project setup, but I'd need more info to be sure. (FWIW, I am using Visual Studio, but the IDE shouldn't really matter.) Here's a suggestion: Try adding `using FSharpLibrary;` to your Program.cs file. Does that compile?

Comment: Hello Brian, I got it to compile and it is working nicely. The only thing is that it gives errors in my Blazor project on every occasion where I use ' usingFSharpLibary' or a function from the FSharpLibrary. So my project is full of red warnings(but it compiles and runs!). Another thing is that Intellisense doesn't work on the F# functions. I am using VS Code under Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: It sounds like the Intellisense information in VS Code is out of date somehow. Does it help if you close VS Code completely and then restart it? Unfortunately, I don't have a lot of experience with VS Code.